# What is the best way to assign the String.Empty values to the property if it is Null using asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a column in the database which is Name its string with null value.

when I dont enter anything in the  Name Field its saving to the database as NULL.

but I need to save this value as string.Empty or "".

I did soemthing like this.

```
   h.assignedName= m.Name== null ? string.Empty : m.Name;
```

ViewModel Property has

```
Public string Name {get;set;}
```

my question is any other way we can assign this value has String.Empty without doing any condition like above?

I dont want to use ? operator to check the condition or if condition.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jason's idea is sound assuming you do not care about making that minor change.
Another way you could do it is to abandon your automatic property and handle the checking in the get

```
private string name;
public string Name
{
   get { return (name == null) ? string.Empty : name; }
}
```

This obviously has more initial code over head for all properties that you want to utilize this style.

or you could ensure it is never null in your constructors

Answer (score 2):

You could change the column in the database to not be `NULL` and set the default value to ''. That way you would not have to use the ? conditional. Not sure if this is best practise, but it would save you having to add additional code to cater for it.

The other way is to create a wrapper class around the data. I see you're using `m.Name` in your code example. You could have:

```
    public class MyWrapper
    {
        private string _name;

        public string Name
        {
            get {
                 if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_name)){
                   return String.Empty;
                 }

                 return _name;
           }

          set{
     _name = value;
}
       }
    }
```

So when you're reading the data from the database, create an instance of your wrapper class to hide the details when getting the Name.

Comment: Please can you tell me how to set the value to "" if the database value as not NULL?

Comment: which one your saying not the best practice?

Comment: Thanks Jas. If I use this property to set the Empty value in my ViewModel. is that ok to have the database column as null value field?

Answer (score 0):

You might consider changing the layout of your code construction and use a business rule like
"m.Name may never be null." And then you should initialize it as String.Empty, so that it can never be null.